# Find records with disjoint dates

Tags: sql-server

Consider the following table,

```
CREATE TABLE temp ( 
    [TabName] VARCHAR(255),
    [ID] VARCHAR(255),
    [AsOfDate] DATE)

  INSERT INTO temp VALUES 
    ('TAB1', 'C103', '2019-05-01'),
    ('TAB1', 'C103', '2019-06-01'),
    ('TAB2', 'C103', '2019-06-01'),
    ('TAB2', 'C103', '2019-07-01'),
    ('TAB1', 'C103', '2019-09-01'),
    ('TAB1', 'C104', '2019-06-01'),
    ('TAB1', 'C104', '2019-08-01')
```

```
TabName     ID      AsOfDate      
TAB1        C103     '2019-05-01'            
TAB1        C103     '2019-06-01'                        
TAB2        C103     '2019-06-01'                                    
TAB2        C103     '2019-07-01'     
TAB1        C103     '2019-09-01'
TAB1        C104     '2019-06-01'
TAB1        C104     '2019-08-01'
TAB1        C105     '2019-04-01'
TAB1        C105     '2019-05-01'
```

I am wanting to find the IDs from the table that have skipped dates. In this table, I would want to identify that ID C103 and C104 have skipped dates as they have jumped from '2019-07-01' to '2019-09-01' and '2019-06-01' to '2019-8-01' respectively.

I have found the following question asked previously [Find Missing Dates in Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643876/find-missing-dates-in-data) which I believe gives some potential clues on the approach, i.e. using CTE, however, I am unsure how to apply them to this question where the dates are not consecutive across the whole table.

Should we be looking at partitioning here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to achieve this, in conjunction with two windowing functions ([ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)), to produce a running total of the date difference between the current date value and the previous value (by tabname & id group). You then SELECT only those rows with a date difference higher than 1.

If you're on SQL Server 2012 or higher, there is a much simpler way. Use the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to retrieve the previous value (grouped by tabname and id) and performt he DATEDIFF on that.

Examples are included below, and you can see them in action in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc5aadfd2fa44daad13c13876f370d8f).

LAG Example:

```
SELECT
  TabName,
  Id,
  AsOfDate
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TabName,
    Id,
    AsOfDate,
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(AsOfDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TabName, Id ORDER BY AsOfDate), AsOfDate), 0) AS PrevDateDiff
  FROM Temp
) t
WHERE t.PrevDateDiff > 1
ORDER BY tabname, id, asofdate
```

Recursive CTE example:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    TabName,
    Id,
    AsOfDate,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TabName, Id) AS Grp,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TabName, Id ORDER BY AsOfDate) AS Rn
  FROM Temp
), CTE2 AS
(
  SELECT c1.TabName,
    c1.Id,
    c1.AsOfDate,
    c1.Grp,
    c1.Rn,
    0 AS DateDiff
  FROM CTE c1
  WHERE c1.Rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c1.TabName,
    c1.Id,
    c1.AsOfDate,
    c1.Grp,
    c1.Rn,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, c2.AsOfDate, c1.AsOfDate) AS DateDiff
  FROM CTE c1
  INNER JOIN CTE2 c2 ON c2.Rn = c1.Rn - 1 AND c2.Grp = c1.Grp
  WHERE c1.Rn > 1
)

SELECT
  TabName,
  Id,
  AsOfDate
FROM CTE2
WHERE DateDiff > 1
ORDER BY tabname, id, asofdate
```

Answer (score 1):

First Create Calendar Table.

Populate in whatever way you want.

```
create table CalendarDate(Dates DateTime primary key)
insert into CalendarDate WITH (TABLOCK)  (Dates)
select top (1000000) 
DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))-1,'1970-01-01') DT
from sys.objects
```

Then,

```
CREATE TABLE #RealTable ( 
    [TabName] VARCHAR(255),
    [ID] VARCHAR(255),
    [AsOfDate] DATE)

  INSERT INTO #RealTable VALUES 
    ('TAB1', 'C103', '2019-05-01'),
    ('TAB1', 'C103', '2019-05-02'),
    ('TAB2', 'C103', '2019-05-03'),
    ('TAB2', 'C103', '2019-05-05'),
    ('TAB1', 'C103', '2019-05-06'),
    ('TAB1', 'C104', '2019-06-01'),
    ('TAB1', 'C104', '2019-06-03')


;with CTE as
(
select [ID],max(AsOfDate) MxDT,min(AsOfDate)MinDt 
from  #RealTable
group by [ID]
)
,CTE1 as
(
select cd.Dates,c.id 
from CalendarDate cd,CTE c
where cd.Dates>=MinDt and  cd.Dates<=MxDt
)
select * from CTE1 c
where 
not exists
(select * from #RealTable t 
where c.ID=t.ID and c.Dates=t.AsOfDate )


drop table #RealTable
```